# Java 8 -Firmar el certificado CADES-T con el hash SHA-256 del ID de aplicacion

Tags: java, java-8, certificado-ssl, sha256

Estoy desarrollando una clase en Java 8 que consiste en una firma CADES-T en BASE64 del hash SHA-256 de una variable que he llamado **idAplicacion**.

Tengo dos certificados: uno público (extension *.cer*) y uno privado(extension *.p12*) con su contraseña.

Basandome con la ayuda de la IA he desarrollado mi clase con el siguiente contenido:

```
String idAplicacion = "idAplicacion";
String ficheroP12 = "PRUEBAS.p12";
char[] password = "password".toCharArray();

//Cargar el certificado CADES-T
InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(ficheroP12);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(inStream, password);
String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
            
//Calcular el hash SHA-256 del IdAplicacion
MessageDigest messageDigest =  MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
messageDigest.update(idAplicacion.getBytes());
byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest();
            
//Firmar el certificado CADES-T con el hash SHA-256 del ID de aplicacion
X509Certificate signedCertificate = certificate.createCertificate(hash);
                    
            
//Enconde the signed certificate in base64
byte[] signedCertificateBytes = signedCertificate.getEncoded();
String signedCertificateBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signedCertificateBytes);
            
//Mostrar el certificado firmado en base64
System.out.println("Firma CADES-T" + signedCertificateBase64);
```

El problema lo tengo en la línea que pone **X509Certificate signedCertificate = certificate.createCertificate(hash);** puesto que la librería *java.security.cert.X509Certificate* no reconoce el método *createCertificate*. No sé si estoy utilizando la versión correcta o necesitaría crear un método para relacionarlo.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.